# How to override component in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I want to override one of existing component in my custom module.

Here is the component -

```
import {SeComponent, TypedMap} from "smarteditcommons";
import {
GenericEditorField,
GenericEditorSanitizationService, IGenericEditor, SeRichTextFieldLocalizationService,
SeRichTextLoaderService
} from "smarteditcommons/components/genericEditor";
import "ckeditor";

@SeComponent({
templateUrl: 'seRichTextFieldComponentTemplate.html',
inputs: [
    'field:=',
    'qualifier:=',
    'model:=',
    'editor:=',
    'isDisabled'
]
})
export class SeRichTextFieldComponent {

public field: GenericEditorField;
public qualifier: string;
public model: TypedMap<any>;
public editor: IGenericEditor;

private mode: string;
private editorInstance: CKEDITOR.editor;

constructor(
    private seRichTextLoaderService: SeRichTextLoaderService,
    private seRichTextConfiguration: any,
    private genericEditorSanitizationService: GenericEditorSanitizationService,
    private seRichTextFieldLocalizationService: SeRichTextFieldLocalizationService,
    private $scope: angular.IScope,
    private $element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery
) {
    this.seRichTextLoaderService.load().then(() => {
        const textAreaElement = this.$element.find('textarea')[0] as HTMLTextAreaElement;
        this.editorInstance = CKEDITOR.replace(textAreaElement, this.seRichTextConfiguration);

        this.seRichTextFieldLocalizationService.localizeCKEditor();

        this.$element.bind('$destroy', () => {
            if (this.editorInstance && CKEDITOR.instances[this.editorInstance.name]) {
                CKEDITOR.instances[this.editorInstance.name].destroy();
            }
        });

        this.editorInstance.on('change', this.onChange.bind(this));
        this.editorInstance.on('mode', this.onMode.bind(this));
        CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', this.onInstanceReady.bind(this));
    });
}
}
```

**I want to override its constructor with some custom logic in my module.** So i created same component with different name say **CustomRichTextFieldComponent**.

```
@SeComponent({
templateUrl: 'seRichTextFieldComponentTemplate.html',
inputs: [
    'field:=',
    'qualifier:=',
    'model:=',
    'editor:=',
    'isDisabled'
]
})
export class CustomRichTextFieldComponent extends SeRichTextFieldComponent {

public field: GenericEditorField;
public qualifier: string;
public model: TypedMap<any>;
public editor: IGenericEditor;

private mode: string;
private editorInstance: CKEDITOR.editor;

constructor(
    private seRichTextLoaderService: SeRichTextLoaderService,
    private seRichTextConfiguration: any,
    private genericEditorSanitizationService: GenericEditorSanitizationService,
    private seRichTextFieldLocalizationService: SeRichTextFieldLocalizationService,
    private $scope: angular.IScope,
    private $element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery
) {
     // custom changes
     super();
  }
}
```

To use this component in my module I am trying something like this ..

```
angular.module('customRichTextModule', []).component('seRichTextFieldComponent', {
controller: ['CustomRichTextFieldComponent']});
```

But its not working. What is the correct way to do ?

Comment: spend some time to provide minimal example not just copy-paste tons of code

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I am just looking a way to override component in angularJs.

Comment: This is Angular, not AngularJS

Comment: @JerMah : Ok. Can you please help me overriding component constructor ?

Comment: Added more info

Answer (score 0):

If you want your **Component** two have a different behaviour in another **Module**, the right way is to inject a **Service** with a different value to that **Module**. Then read the value from component and decide what to do.

In your service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
 type;

 constructor(type){
  this.type = type;
 }
}
```

In your module (each module a differnt value in constructor):

```
  providers: [
    { provide: MyService , useValue: new MyService(1)},
```

And finaly in your component:

```
contructor(private service: MyService){
 if(service.type == 1){
  // do a different thing
 }
}
```