# How to override dependency in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have one module.ts file -

```js
export const SE_RICH_TEXT_CONFIGURATION_CONSTANT: SeValueProvider = {
  provide: "seRichTextConfiguration",
  useValue: {
    toolbar: "full",
    toolbar_full: [
      // Some Configuration
    ]
  }
};

@SeModule({
  imports: ["ngSanitize", "smarteditServicesModule"],
  providers: [SE_RICH_TEXT_CONFIGURATION_CONSTANT],
  declarations: [SeRichTextFieldComponent]
})
export class SeRichTextFieldModule {}
```

I had a requirement to override `SE_RICH_TEXT_CONFIGURATION_CONSTANT` so I managed to do something like this and its working fine

**Created new customRichTextModule.ts file & override constant**

```js
var CUSTOM_RICH_TEXT_CONFIGURATION_CONSTANT = {
  name: "seRichTextConfiguration",
  useValue: {
    toolbar: "custom",
    toolbar_custom: [
      // Custom Configuration
    ]
  }
};

angular
  .module("customRichTextModule", [
    "seRichTextFieldModule",
    "ngSanitize",
    "smarteditServicesModule"
  ])
  .constant(
    CUSTOM_RICH_TEXT_CONFIGURATION_CONSTANT.name,
    CUSTOM_RICH_TEXT_CONFIGURATION_CONSTANT.useValue
  );
```

And Finally added my custom module in the root module.

**Now I want to override declarations as well.  How to do that ?**

```js
declarations: [
  SeRichTextFieldComponent // Wants to override this
];
```

Comment: You can't override anything in `declarations`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I want to do some customisation SeRichTextFieldComponent, thinking to create new custom component and change the dependency in my custom module. Any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can't replace components, directives, or pipes using dependency injection.

Comment: @AluanHaddad : Please suggest the way

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to abstract the actual text field component that is used so that the code using `SeRichTextFieldModule` can specify which component it uses for text fields. Is that about right?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Actually i am working on one angular based application where i can't change anything directly. The only way is to override/extend existing behaviour. As i mentioned in my question, there was a requirement to change constant value in module.ts so i created my custom module.ts and change the constant. SeRichTextFieldComponent is responsible for showing RichText editor. i want to add my custom code in that component but i can't add directly in same component, i m looking a way to override that component.

Comment: @AluanHaddad if you want to see component source code, please refer my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950970/how-to-override-component-in-angularjs

Comment: It will not be possible with zero changes. The components that use `SeRichTextFieldComponent` will have to be changed to dynamically load that component. If you are used to AngularJS, Angular is far less dynamic and far less flexible.